# how to include an inc.php file in zend framework project?

Tags: php, zend-framework, include

I'm working on a porting of a simple project to a zend framework project using zf 1.10.8.
there are 3 or 4 .inc.php files that I need present in let's say 2 layouts.
my first idea is to load them in the boostrap but I've realized that they are not needed every where in the project so I've started questioning that idea.

Secondly I wanted to put them in views but realized some of them are classes.so I ended up confused.

What's the best way to implement that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

just include them where you need them.
If they include classes, instantiate the classes as you need them

```
// someview.phtml
include '/path/to/needed.php'; // contains class Foo
$foo = new Foo;
```

As an alternative, port the classes to use the ZF/PEAR naming convention and make them available to the Zend Autoloader. Or create a wrapper class that includes the files and have that wrapper loaded by the Autoloader. Or add a ViewHelper that includes them.